# Spring AOP logger trace ID with Spring Cloud Sleuth?

Tags: java, logging, aop, spring-aop, spring-cloud-sleuth

I have a few microservices running with Spring Cloud Sleuth as a distributed logging manager. For some microservices Spring AOP is also included, mostly with `@Around` advice for methods execution time logging (code below).

Now, I'm probably missing AOP point here and don't really understand when `@Around` advice actually kicks in, but is it possible to have Sleuth trace ID included in log generated from `@Aspect` defined class ?

Code:

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface LogExecutionTime {
}
```

`@Aspect` class (imports from `org.aspectj` and `org.slf4j`):

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class PerformanceAspect {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PerformanceAspect.class);

@Around("@annotation(LogExecutionTime)")
public Object logExecutionTime(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    final long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    final Object proceed = joinPoint.proceed();

    final long executionTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;

    logger.debug("\n---- Performance aspect ----\n" +
                "method: {}\n" +
                "execution time: {} [ms]\n" +
                "------------------------\n",
            joinPoint.getSignature().getName(), executionTime);

    return proceed;
    }
}
```

Spring Boot version is 2.0.7.RELEASE (Spring Cloud Finchley.SR2) and the related (Maven) dependencies are:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

`@LogExecutionTime` is set on some of time-critical methods (file upload to storage, external API calls, etc.), and it is much desirable if user actions trace ID could also be set for methods performance logging.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

**UPDATE:**

There are trace IDs for other logs, here is example:

```
January 31st 2019, 09:44:31.024 dev-backend customer-service    31.01.2019 08:44:50 DEBUG [customer-service,f9c173ae7a161cd6,f9c173ae7a161cd6,false] Request for file upload.
```

Right after that, here are performance logs (without trace ID):

```
January 31st 2019, 09:44:50.532 dev-backend customer-service    method: fileUploadAzure

January 31st 2019, 09:44:50.532 dev-backend customer-service    ---- Performance aspect ----

January 31st 2019, 09:44:50.532 dev-backend customer-service    execution time: 19507 [ms]
```

Imports in both cases are:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
```

Logging pattern from config:

```
logging:
  // other config
  pattern:
    console: "%d{dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss} ${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN:-%5p} %m%n"
```

Comment: Do you see trace IDs in any other logs in your application (i.e. are you using the correct logging library and format spec)? Aspects don't really have any special status.

Comment: Yes, I can see them. I've updated question with that additional info.

Comment: The log formats look different to me. Are you sure it’s the same logging system?

Comment: I’ve copied full log entry from Kibana, so the first part to “dev-backend customer-service” is Kibana default format entry. The part after “dev-backend customer-service” is logging format of my microservice, so we can focus on that part only.

Comment: I’m sure it’s the same logging system. Do you want me to provide some additional informations or parts of code ? Thank you.

Comment: I don't know what else I can suggest. Maybe you could create a project that reproduces the issue? I don't think there is enough information here yet, but clearly your log format is not being used in the aspect.

Comment: I just realized the log snippets you pasted from the aspect were from a log message that includes embedded new lines (`\n`) and you didn't show the rest of the message. If I were you I would concentrate on the problem when you can see the raw logs in a console (not the Kibana output).

Comment: Thank you mr. Syer, you were right. I was concentrating too much on debugging through Elasticsearch entries and Kibana, where separated line entries happened. One of the entries is also Sleuth-patterned log prefix that represents beginning of full performance log, but because of new line separation it was scattered in Kibana and hardly noticeable because of large number of logs. At the end it was a silly “problem” and it’s not about Spring AOP at all. I started believing that Aspects have some special status in all of this :( I’m really grateful for your time, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: don't use line separators in logs (`\n`) if you want to analyse all lines with Kibana and see the trace id on every line.